# Есть ли решение для обучения модели со вложенными списками в векторе признаков?

Tags: python, r, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

```
f_1 = 1
f_2 = 0
X_train = [[f_1, f_2], [f_2, f_1]]
y_train = [1, -1]
```

Мой набор данных содержит в переменных f_1 и f_2 вложенные списки.

```
f_1 = [[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]]
```

Вопрос в том, реально ли написать, например, персептрон для обучения именно на такой структуре данных?
Пробовал агрегировать и разворачивать вложенные признаки в один вектор, результат плохой, хотя признаки информативные (но это не точно).

Думаю есть что-то подобное для работы с изображениями из области глубокого обучения, но в моём случае данные неоднородные...